# Maintain two exclusive types of User in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have two distinctly different types of User in a django project: **Trainer** and **Client**.

I have models for them like so:

```
class TrainerProfile(model.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    #...other Trainer fields

class ClientProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    #...other Trainer fields
```

The problem I am facing is how can I explicitly enforce that a User can be only one of these, and then query which one they are?

Comment: Why not just have one Profile model with a field that says which type it is?

Comment: @Carlos Which would be the best datatype of the field specifying the type? Some integer for example 0=TrainerProfile, and 1=ClientProfile ?

Comment: Yeah you have plenty of choice. I'd go with an int or some other enum-like type since it looks like there's going to be a limited amount of choices.